# How can I make an automatic updater for my visual studio 2010 c++ application?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, auto-update

How can I make an automatic updater for my visual studio 2010 c++ application ? I do not want any kind of advanced features. 
Any free application that can provide a notification that "A new version 1.2.2 is available" ?

Actually right now I just want only notification to the user not download the software or something like that.

When a user run the application then simple check the new version, if available then a message box or notification appears.

My idea is that the application simple check a "http://www.site.com/update.txt" file which has a number if number increment in future, then msg box appears that "a new version is available, Visit website" .. its simple but how can I check in VS2010 C++ ?

Comment: You know how do pull a file via http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparkle is the best choice I found. Its amazing. Here you go http://winsparkle.org/

Answer (score 1):

<sup>I don't know Windows, but....</sup>

You could use some HTTP client library, perhaps [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), to issue a `GET` HTTP request to your `http://www.site.com/update.txt` URL.

But don't overwrite magically the binary executable.

Comment: For windows and C++ this might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx

Comment: @alk . I got an error when I complied Microsoft source code.

Command line error D8016: '/EHs' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible

Answer (score 1):

How about using ClickOnce deployment? I's very easy to use in C#, more complicated in C++, but MSDN tells that it is possible:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235287%28v=vs.100%29.aspx